# Python import in __init__()

Tags: python, python-import

I need to have an import in `__init__()` method (because i need to run that import only when i instance the class).

But i cannot see that import outside `__init__()`, is the scope limited to`__init__`? how to do?

Comment: The import is bound to the scope it's imported in... I get the feeling you don't want to be doing this though, what's your use case?

Comment: Why do you only want to import it in `__init__()` if you need it in other scopes too?

Comment: because i have a class with a dependency, and i want that dependency loaded only if someone is using that class (creates an instance)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Imported names are bound to the current scope, so an import inside a function binds to a local name only.

If you absolutely *have* to import something in `__init__` that then needs to be globally avaliable, mark the imported name as `global` first:

```
>>> def foo():
...     global sys
...     import sys
... 
>>> sys
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'sys' is not defined
>>> foo()
>>> sys
<module 'sys' (built-in)>
```

but this usually leads to strange and wonderfully difficult to locate bugs. Don't do that, just make your imports at module scope instead.

If you need the imported name within other class methods, you could also assign the imported name to a instance variable:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        import os
        self.join = os.path.join
```

but again, that's not the best practice to use.

Comment: What would you recommend then? I have a abstract class (abc) and a class that holds classes implementing that abc class. And a function that based on a string searches for a class that would implement this abc class and then call it's function prepare (required by abstract). Those functions may require totally different stuff, like one does need sqlite and other xml parser.

Comment: Perhaps put those implementations into their own module? But really, what's the problem with just putting those imports at the top level?

Comment: Own module is out of a question, because dir() is too obfuscated and to many stuff to validate (and potentially to break code). At top level is also out of a question, because some of the classess require large modules, like sqlite, tkinter, minidom etc. and we don't want to import them at module import, only a subset of them according to which class we require.

Answer (score 6):

You can just import it again other places that you need it -- it will be cached after the first time so this is relatively inexpensive.

Alternatively you could modify the current global namespaces with something like `globals()['name'] = local_imported_module_name`.

**EDIT**: For the record, although using the `globals()` function will certainly work, I think a "cleaner" solution would be to declare the module's name `global` and then `import` it, as several other answers have mentioned.

Comment: `import it again` is the right solution. It's free, because module imports are cached globally in `sys.modules`.

Comment: @katrielalex: That's what I meant by the "it will be cached" part.

Comment: Agree -- I was just emphasising =)

Answer (score 5):

The `import` statement makes the imported names only available to the current scope. An `import foo` inside your `__init__` creates a `foo` which is only visible within the `__init__` method.

You could either add the `import foo` to any method which needs to access the module or if you find yourself writing the import over an over again use the `global` keyword to import it to the module scope.

```
class Wayne(object):
    def __init__(self):
        global foo
        import foo
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want the result of your import to be visible to other objects of the class, you would need to assign the resulting object from your import to a class or instance variable

For example:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...    def __init__(self):
...       import math
...       self.bar = math.pi
...    def zoo(self):
...       return self.bar
... 
>>> a = Foo()
>>> a.zoo()
3.141592653589793
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but I think the OP wants something more like `Foo.math =` or `self.math = math` -- i.e. the whole module.